¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionar esto o cómo puedo identificar correctamente esos elementos en Appium Inspector?
Estoy realizando pruebas con Appium Inspector y tengo un problema al intentar identificar elementos específicos. Hay un elemento que, al hacer clic, despliega un cuadro emergente con más elementos. Sin embargo, cuando intento seleccionarlos, aparece un recuadro (de color azul o amarillo) que cubre toda la pantalla, lo que me impide identificar cada elemento individual dentro del cuadro. ¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionar esto o cómo puedo identificar correctamente esos elementos?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
